# I need help adding the consonant ascii values between two letters in java

Tags: java

Instructions:
Write a method called sumConsonants that will take as arguments two
upper case letters. Your function should return a sum of all the ascii values of
the consonants between the starting character and the ending character. Your 
main method should pass two values to the function and output the sum of all the
consonant character values including the first and the last.

For example, if the input was AE, then the program would add all the consonant values between A and E, which would be B(66), C(67), D(68), which would add up to 201. Even if the input was EA then it would still add up to the same thing.

I'm stuck on the for loop method. Thank you!

This is what I have so far...

```
public int sumConsonants(int a, int b) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= b; i++) {
        if ( i == 'A' || i == 'E' || i == 'I' || i == 'O' || i == 'U' )
            ;
        else 
            sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Assignment11 c = new Assignment11();
    int a,b;
    System.out.println("Enter two uppercase characters");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String upper = s.toUpperCase();
    a = upper.charAt(0);
    b = upper.charAt(1);
    System.out.println("The sum of the consonants is " + c.sumConsonants(a,b));
}
```

Comment: Å and Æ are uppercase letters, too, so I suggest that you change "Enter two uppercase characters" to "Enter two [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) uppercase characters (A-Z)". Then you can get by with a comment like `charAt(0); // despite returning a UTF-16 code unit, the ASCII value is the same for valid inputs`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop overreaches with the number of values it pulls in.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= b; i++)
```

This should be bound between `a` and `b`.

```
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
```

In order to ensure that you get the minimum value as your lower bound (assumed `a`), and the maximum value as your upper bound (assumed `b`), you'll need to take the minimum and maximum of these two values, but I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The question uses an exclusive range.  Your answer uses an inclusive range.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc:  The question has always had an inclusive range.  Not sure where you saw just `<` at.

Comment: Quoting from the original poster. *For example, if the input was AE, then the program would add all the consonant values between A and E, which would be B(66), C(67), D(68), which would add up to 201.*

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc E isn't a consonant so it wouldn't factor in the sum.  If it were AF then F would need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

1st - Order your input alphabetically, so in the case of EA... you change it to AE

2nd - Load each letter/ASCII pair into a HashMap

3rd - Iterate through each entry in the HashMap, and turn the summing "on" when you hit the first letter... and off when you hit the 2nd letter.

4th - Return sum